# Echoing Jquery "contains" statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, echo

I have php file where I echo JQuery code where I check if checkboxes are checked and than do stuff if they are. But if I use `contains()` code does nothing.

This code works:

```
"<script type='text/javascript'> 
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#filterbutton').click(function() {
      if($('#znackaasus').is(':checked')) {
        console.log('checked');
      }
    });
  }); 
</script>"
```

But this code breaks whole jQuery and does nothing:

```
"<script type='text/javascript'> 
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#filterbutton').click(function() {
      if($('#znackaasus').is(':checked')) {
        $('.tovar:contains('ASUS')').hide();
      }
    });
  }); 
</script>"
```

Comment: Too many `'` in a string

Comment: `$('.tovar:contains('ASUS')')` is not valid because of quotes inside quotes of the same type...

Comment: Quite often a single JavaScript error will stop all JavaScript running

Comment: try changing `$('.tovar:contains('ASUS')')` to `$('.tovar').contains('ASUS')`

Comment: @Pete I get error in console if I change it that way: **TypeError: $(...).contains is not a function[Learn More]**

Comment: It's definitely a function of jquery: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/.  Why are you echoing out script blocks like that anyway.  Just break out of the php and write is as normal script - you shouldn't echo massive blocks of html / js as you run into these quote mismatch errors and make it harder to maintain and format

Comment: Maybe this will make you see the value of closing the PHP tag and opening later instead of echoing.

Comment: @Pete yeah I guess I have no other choice but to write it regular way. I hoped it can be done this way but quotes are problem I guess. Thanks for help anyway

Comment: Please post your actual html markup and make sure you have jquery loaded properly. Your code seems to work fine, assuming the markup [http://plnkr.co/edit/6SZGMANbkVqLeINFjabn?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/6SZGMANbkVqLeINFjabn?p=preview)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This:

```
"<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#filterbutton').click(function() {
if($('#znackaasus').is(':checked'))
    {
     $(\".tovar:contains('ASUS')\").hide();
    }
});
}); 
</script>"
```

Unsure if this will work as expected, but it might.

Comment: Oh, this actually works. I didn't realise I can use escape character this way. Thanks man.